# Problems using jQuery toggle class and attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

I have a button which I want to toggle the class "disabled" and the attribute `disabled = "disabled"` using jQuery based on some condition, but it doesn't.
Also, what is the diference between Attr and prop. 
What I expect is that :

```
if ($("#result").text() == 'Deve inserir no minimo 2 caractéres para válidação..' || $( "#result" ).text() == 'Este código já foi inserido tente outro') {
  // then add the class disabled in the button
  // and add the attr disabled in the button
} else {
  // then remove the class disabled
  // and remove the attr disabled
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#codAssembleia').keyup(function() {
      var codAssembleia = $('#codAssembleia').val();

      if (codAssembleia.length > 2) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo base_url();?>forms_de_preenchimento/Preenchimento_Controller/verificarCodAssembleia",
          method: "POST",
          data: {
            codAssembleia: codAssembleia
          },
          success: function(data) {
            //alert("Changed!");
            $('#result').html(data);
          }
        });
      } else {
        //alert("Not Changed!");
        $('#result').html('<small class="text-secundary">Deve inserir no minimo 2 caractéres para válidação..</small>');
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#codAssembleia').keyup(function() {
      if ($("#result").text() == 'Deve inserir no minimo 2 caractéres para válidação..' || $("#result").text() == 'Este código já foi inserido tente outro') {
        $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#submit").addClass("disabled");

      } else {
        $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#submit").removeClass("disabled");
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success disabled" disabled="disabled" value="save">Submeter <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Código Da Assembleia</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control integerInput" id="codAssembleia" name="codAssembleia" placeholder="Introduza o código da assembleia de votos .." required>
  <p id="result"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to use

```
      if ($("#result").text() == 'Deve inserir no minimo 2 caractéres para válidação..' || $("#result").text() == 'Este código já foi inserido tente outro') {
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", true); //here is a change in your code
        $("#submit").addClass("disabled");

      } else {
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", false); //here is a change in your code
        $("#submit").removeClass("disabled");
      }
```

Comment: I just changed and the result is still not what i expect, because its only running the first condition : $("#result").text() == 'Deve inserir no minimo 2 caractéres para válidação..' i dont really know why!! :/

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple example of what i think you are trying to do, and it is working fine.

```
  <body>
    <div>
      <input id="inp" type="text" />
      <p id="result"></p>
      <button id="submit">
        submit
      </button>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#inp").keyup(() => {
          const result = $("#result");
          if ($("#inp").val().length > 2) {
            result.text("we do something");
          } else {
            result.text("enter something");
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#inp").keyup(() => {
          const submit = $("#submit");
          if ($("#result").text() == "enter something") {
            submit.prop("disabled", true);
          } else {
            submit.prop("disabled", false);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

did you checked if the api is returning the right data?

Comment: See thats the thing even this code you just made isn't working !!

Comment: why? I think that the button is disabled/enabled correctly after the changes are made to the input

Comment: When i put your code in my page it doesn't work at all !!

Comment: i think the problem with your code is that you are making a post request at every keyup!! is that what you want? or you want the user to submit the input via the submit button?

Comment: I though the same think and came out with a simple solution.. using a hidden input to store the value 1 and 0 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I just figure a different way to solve this issue..
Instead of using 2 diferent scripts and bought scripts with the same function keyup i just joined the 2 scripts in one. and it worked. I think that one script was interfiering in the other script keyup function.

Heres the code that i solved the issue :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#codAssembleia').keyup(function(){

            var codAssembleia = $('#codAssembleia').val();

            if(codAssembleia.length > 2) {

                $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>forms_de_preenchimento/Preenchimento_Controller/verificarCodAssembleia",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{codAssembleia : codAssembleia},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        //alert("Changed!");
                        $('#result').html(data);

                        if($("#codState").val() == 0)
                        {
                            $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
                            $("#submit").addClass("disabled");

                        }

                        if($("#codState").val() == 1)
                        {
                            $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
                            $("#submit").removeClass("disabled");
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                //alert("Not Changed!");
                $('#result').html('<small class="text-secundary">Deve inserir no minimo 2 caractéres para válidação..</small><input type="hidden" name="codState" id="codState" value="0">');
                $("#submit").addClass("disabled");
                $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
            }

        });

    }); 
</script>
```

I also used a hidden field $("#codState") to store the values 1 and 0 that come out from the data request ajax.